# Delete onenote using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, onenote

I have multiple OneNote inside site assets library. I want to delete the one note which is created on my name. I am using SharePoint online sites I want to delete it using PowerShell. pls some one help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Connect-PnPOnline -url "" -SPOManagementShell
    #$Web = Get-PnPWeb 
    #$Title = $Web.Title
    $Title = $SiteCollection.dSiteName.Replace('/','-') + " " + "Notebook"
    $AuthorEmail = ""
    $Documents = ""

    $ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $Documents -PageSize 500 | where {($_.FieldValues.Author.Email -eq $AuthorEmail) -and ($_.FieldValues.ProgId -eq "OneNote.Notebook")}
    #$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $Documents -PageSize 500 | where {($_.FieldValues.Author.Email -eq $AuthorEmail) -and ($_.FieldValues.ProgId -eq "OneNote.Notebook") -and ($_.FieldValues.FileLeafRef -eq $Title)}  
    $FileName = $ListItems["FileLeafRef"] 
    Write-Host $FileName
    Write-Host $ListItems.Id

   Remove-PnPListItem -List $Documents -Identity $ListItems.Id -Force
    if($FileName -eq $Title)
    {
    
    Remove-PnPListItem -List $Documents -Identity $ListItems.Id -Force
    Write-Host "OneNote is Deleted" -ForegroundColor Green  
    }

    else{
    Write-Host "OneNote cannot be found"
}
```

Comment: HI Liz. Thanks  for your sharing, you can accept your answer as answer. The behavior will help others who meet the similar issue in the future quickly find the correct answer.

Comment: Yes i marked this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, we cannot delete OneNote notebooks in SharePoint Online through PowerShell.

We can only manually delete OneNote notebooks from the Site Assets library.

Comment: finally i have written code to do this.